# Design decision as to provide a single ejb component which invokes other specific ejb components

Tags: java

we have multiple buisiness format converter ejb components which do the following tasks
     if the data submitted to them is xml , then convert from xml to corresponding format
     else assume it is the buisiness format and convet it to the xml.
now we have a requirement to have single converter component which can pick up the right converter component based on the format of xml passed to it.

how would I decide which component to choose, because the ability to understand the format lies within the specific component?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this using a [chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). Inject all the possible EJBs to the single Converter EJB and let the latter build up the chain. Each of the concrete converters implement an interface which provides some method like `boolean canHandle(XML xml)`. Once one returns true let it handle the xml and return.